Can I play Xerosic's Machinations when my opponent has 4 cards in their hand?
The card is a supporter whose text reads:

Your opponent discards cards from their hand until they have 3 cards in their hand.

When playing on Pokemon TCG Live, the game did not allow me to use the card when my opponent only had 4 cards in hand (I could otherwise play supporters that turn) despite my opponent ostensibly being able to discard down to 4. The only interpretation I could see preventing the card being played is the plural in "cards" mattering, meaning my opponent needs to be able to discard multiple cards and not just the one, making the minimum 5.
Is PTCGL correct in its interpretation of the card or is this a bug? Is there a TCG rule that explicitly clarifies whether the plural "cards" should be taken literally?

That sounds like a bug, have you reached out to the game developer to ask?

Pokemon support is notoriously slow to reply so I figured I'd ask here in case anyone else got confused or overly pedantic in a physical game

Rules-wise, yes this should work fine:

Your opponent discards cards from their hand until they have 3 cards in their hand.

One card would satisfy "discards cards".  You cannot play this if your opponent has three cards in their hand, but are welcome to play it if they have four or more.
See for example, this compendium entry on playing cards for no effect:

You cannot play a card if it is public knowledge that it will have no game effect. Paying a cost does not satisfy the requirement that the card has a game effect.


Why couldn't you play that card if they have three or fewer cards in their hands? Sure it will do nothing but what is stopping you from playing it?

I can't find a specific ruling for this but iirc if you know a card will have no effect you cannot play it (e.g. poffin on a full bench, searching an empty deck, retrieving from an empty discard)

Actually found a few relevant rulings: https://compendium.pokegym.net/ruling/1946/ https://compendium.pokegym.net/ruling/1985/
In general, if you know you cannot perform a mandatory action you cannot play the card that invokes this action, so Xerosic's Machinations would not be able to be played when your opponent has 3 or fewer cards

Added the main source for this (it's a meta ruling).  But yes, @JoeW it is not allowed to play a card when it is known it cannot change the game state.  (However, this is very very particular - it has to be knowable right now by someone just walking up as you start to play it.  A deck with 1 card in it that you just super rodded an energy into (so everyone knows it's psychic energy)? Sure, play ultra ball, that's fine - it's not public knowledge even though everyone knows it.

Thanks for that update as it wasn’t clear to me that was the case.
